# Why doesn't this if statement ever get hit?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> dictionary in listOfDictionaries)
{
    if( object.Equals(dictionary, listOfDictionaries.Last() )
    {
        //Do something on last iteration of foreach loop.
    }
}
```

I realized fairly soon on that I wanted a reference equals, but it still brought up the question of how this code could not be hit. Does object.Equals not implicitly know how to compare two Dictionaries, and thus returns not equal?

Comment: You may be running into an issue of using Last() within an iterator.  Some LINQ methods seem to behave nonintuitively in the context of iterators.  Suggestion: Use listOfDictionaries[listOfDictionaries.Count -1] instead.

Comment: This is in general a bad idea, you're not iterating through your collection n times here, you're iterating through it n^2 times since `.Last()` iterates the collection. Maybe use `list.Take(list.Count()-1)` and then `list.Last()`

Comment: I've seen issues of this type show up a lot and wonder why wouldn't you just check the size of the List<T> versus a counter of the number of iterations of the foreach loop?  You cant have multiple threads manipulating listOfDictionaries b/c the foreach really isn't thread-safe, you can't remove objects during a foreach (you'll get an error message at compile time if you try that), so size should be unchanging during the loop, so why not just do what is easy?  (I've seen this here where the question was iterating through a dictionary and comparing to last which is worse b/c that is unordered.

Comment: You can remove items from a foreach if you toList it ;) You're not modifying the same collection reference, but each object in the collection maintains a reference to its counterpart in the original collection. Regardless, my honest answer is just that I found it to be more readable and thought it was a personal-preference choice, not something with a lot of side-effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways the body of the `if` statement could not be hit in this scenario.

1. `listOfDictionaries` is an empty collection hence the `if` statement will never be tested.
2. `listOfDictionaries` could be a generated sequence which returns a new instance of `Dictionary<string, object>` every time it's iterated and hence the elements do not have referential equality between iterations.

Could you give us a bit more context here?  Perhaps show the type of `listOfDictionaries`?

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't require any extra allocations as would be incurred with `.ToList`

```
using (var e = listOfDictionaries.GetEnumerator()) {
  var hasMore = e.MoveNext();
  while (hasMore) {
    var dictionary = e.Current;
    ...
    hasMore = e.MoveNext();
    if (!hasMore) {
      // Inside this if block dictionary is the last item in listOfDictionaries
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: listOfDictionaries has the type: EnumerableRowCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>

It sounds like this fits #2. If I .ToList() my collection to enumerate it explicitly would this be an acceptable way to resolve this?

Comment: @Sean just added another potential solution which doesn't involve the overhead of `ToList` or `Last`

Answer (score 1):

This test passes.

What's not happening as you expect?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        const int length = 10;
        var j = 0;
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> theList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var theDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            theDictionary.Add("string-" + i + "-" + j++, new object());
            theDictionary.Add("string-" + i + "-" + j++, new object());
            theDictionary.Add("string-" + i + "-" + j++, new object());
            theDictionary.Add("string-" + i + "-" + j++, new object());
            theList.Add(theDictionary);
        }

        var theTested = new CodeToTest(theList);

        var returnedValue = theTested.TestThis();

        Assert.AreEqual(returnedValue,length);
    }
}

class CodeToTest
{
    private List<Dictionary<string, object>> listOfDictionaries;

    public CodeToTest(List<Dictionary<string, object>> listOfDictionaries)
    {
        this.listOfDictionaries = listOfDictionaries;
    }

    public int TestThis()
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> dictionary in listOfDictionaries)
        {
            i++;
            if (object.Equals(dictionary, listOfDictionaries.Last()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got here: " + i);
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try having the List of dictionaries be an EnumerableRowCollection and then .ToList() it inside of the foreach declaration. Does this still work? I believe each iteration is getting ToList()'ed which is causing each dictionary to be a different reference.

Comment: @Sean Anderson: Give me some code to generate it as per your question and I'll try.  Just did a little poking, and it's harder than I have time for.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks! Testing helps bring clarity... when there is enough of it.